# if else stament with the typeof check is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, kendo-ui

**updated**

hey I tested your code...its breaking for another scenario if I give mobileVersion as sample.pdf its breaking...I am getting skyCloudmageProfilePic as pdfProfilePic...this is without remove typeOf 
jsfiddle.net/n9d08ko2

where as if I use your conditionI am getting skyCloudmageProfilePic as newDocProfilePic how to get as pdfProfilePic... providing your updated code in this fiddle 
jsfiddle.net/Lqjhyvmz

```
if (model.mobilePics) {
    skyCloudmageProfilePic = model.mobilePics;
 } else {
    skyCloudmageProfilePic = "newDocProfilePic";
 }
```

- I am trying to remove typeof from my if condition.
- if I remove typeof I am getting undefined for skyCloudmageProfilePic.
- is there any way to fix it.
- providing my code below.
- the reson I am trying to remove typeOf is I need to fix the lint error.
- since typeof is not accepted.
- can you tell me how to fix it provding my code below
- I was debugging in this fiddle when it reaches this line  let kendotxtMenu = ""; you can see the value for skyCloudmageProfilePic as newDocProfilePic
  skyCloudmageProfilePic = newDocProfilePic

http://jsfiddle.net/fdnoz2ka/

- but in this fiddle if I remove typeof, you can see the value for skyCloudmageProfilePic as undefined
  skyCloudmageProfilePic = undefined

http://jsfiddle.net/c4k6mqkg/

```or-tag-here
//if (typeof model.mobilePics != "undefined" && model.mobilePics != "") {
          //skyCloudmageProfilePic = model.mobilePics; // skyCloudmageProfilePic = newDocProfilePic
       // }

       //if (typeof skyCloudmageProfilePic == "undefined") {
         // skyCloudmageProfilePic = "newDocProfilePic"; // skyCloudmageProfilePic = newDocProfilePic
       // }

        if ( model.mobilePics != "undefined" && model.mobilePics != "") {
          skyCloudmageProfilePic = model.mobilePics; // skyCloudmageProfilePic = undefined
        }

        if (skyCloudmageProfilePic == "undefined") {
          skyCloudmageProfilePic = "newDocProfilePic"; // skyCloudmageProfilePic = undefined
        }

        let kendotxtMenu = "";
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use a truthy check? `if (model.mobilePics) {}`

Comment: Why would something be the string `"undefined"`, and not just `undefined`,when you're not using `typeof` ?

Comment: @adeneo Because sometimes javascript is screwy ;)

Comment: @Z.Bagley - maybe I should have been clearer, the OP is checking for **the wrong values**, `model.mobilePics` is `undefined`, as in the value `undefined`, not the string `"undefined"`, which is why it isn't working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the Boolean value of the variable to check for defined/undefined state:

```js
var x = 1;
var y = undefined;

if (x) {   // if defined
  console.log("I'm defined");
}
if (!y) {  // if undefined
  console.log("I'm undefined");
}
```

Or, compare the variables with the type `undefined` instead of the string `"undefined"`:

```js
var x = 1;
var y = undefined;

if (x !== undefined) {   // if defined
  console.log("I'm defined");
}
if (y === undefined) {  // if undefined
  console.log("I'm undefined");
}
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail so that in future I can fix it myself

Comment: @jaja If you want to check if a value is true, `if (value)` is the same as `if (value==true)`, and for false, `if (!value)` is the same as `if (value==false)`. And for undefined, you should compare the value with `undefined`, not with the string `"undefined"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (model.mobilePics) {
    skyCloudmageProfilePic = model.mobilePics;
 } else {
    skyCloudmageProfilePic = "newDocProfilePic";
 }
```

This should work, in the first you check for undefined and an empty string, but a string will always evaluate to false if it is either undefined or empty.

After looking a little harder I realized your second check is pointless as well. I've adjusted it to fit better.

You should also use '===' wherever possible, this avoids equality checks doing funky things to you. Here's a little post that explains the triple check.

[Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: hey I tested your code...its breaking for another scenario if I give mobileVersion as sample.pdf its breaking...I am getting skyCloudmageProfilePic as pdfProfilePic...this is without remove typeOf http://jsfiddle.net/n9d08ko2/

Comment: where as if I use your conditionI am getting skyCloudmageProfilePic as newDocProfilePic how to get as pdfProfilePic... providing your updated code in this fiddle   http://jsfiddle.net/Lqjhyvmz/

Comment: After taking a closer look at your entire code, you never give model.mobilePics a value, therefore it will always return 'newDocProfilePic'. I would figure out why you are not giving it a value.